# My printer always asks 'Prevent paper tearing enabled, do you want to continue'. What's bad with that?

Tags: printing, printer, paper

Everytime I print, on my Canon MG5300, it asks 'Prevent paper tearing is enabled, do you want to continue?'. And overtime I wonder "So, why is that bad and why should you warn me?".

I'm getting sick of that question- but as it seems as a positive thing and there isn't an option to disable the warning, besides turning the feature off, I accept the warning and keep it enabled.

Can you guys give advice whether 'Prevent paper tearing enabled' is bad or not- and whether I keep it enabled or rather turn it off.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to look at the user manual but the manual is in the form of a program that must be installed in Windows.  Can you describe what the manual says the feature does or what condition triggers the message?

Comment: Checkin' - Updating this comment in a sec.. If possible :)

Comment: Update: Ok, besides having to install a program to view a file which sucks.. The program doesn't find anything relevant when searching on 'tearing' just as on the display. So.. Nothing in the manual.

Comment: One place you might find information is to contact Canon tech support and ask them.  On the lighter side, I did a Google search on the issue and got one hit--your question.  So apparently, you are the expert.